# My form in phpmailer() only allow send mails from a mail with own domain

Tags: php, forms, email, phpmailer

I have this code and it's a problem because it works when I am sending mails when I am specifing a mail with own domain in the form. But it doesn't work if I using a gmail or Yahoo mail.

This is the code I'm using on PHPMailer:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if (isset($_POST['inputName']) && isset($_POST['inputEmail']) && isset($_POST['inputSubject']) && isset($_POST['inputMessage'])) {

    //check if any of the inputs are empty
    if (empty($_POST['inputName']) || empty($_POST['inputEmail']) || empty($_POST['inputSubject']) || empty($_POST['inputMessage'])) {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    //create an instance of PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Host = "mail.example.com"; // SMTP a utilizar. Por ej. smtp.elserver.com
    $mail->Username = "contacto@example.com"; // Correo completo a utilizar
    $mail->Password = "xxx"; // Contraseña
    $mail->Port = 25; // Puerto a utilizar

    $mail->From = $_POST['inputEmail'];
    $mail->FromName = $_POST['inputName'];
    $mail->AddAddress('contacto@example.net'); //recipient 
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['inputSubject'];
    $mail->Body = "Name: " . $_POST['inputName'] . "\r\n\r\nMessage: " . stripslashes($_POST['inputMessage']);
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    if (isset($_POST['ref'])) {
        $mail->Body .= "\r\n\r\nRef: " . $_POST['ref'];
    }

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'El mensaje no se ha enviado: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    $data = array('success' => true, 'message' => '¡Gracias! Hemos recibido tu mensaje.');
    echo json_encode($data);

} else {

    $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Favor de llenar los campos correctamente.');
    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

Comment: if phpmailer returns true, then its job is done, and you need to check your mail server's logs. PHP's job is the equivalent of taking your envelope and walking it down to the street corner and throwing it in the mailbox. After that, if the mailbox is destroyed, the letter lost, etc... that's not PHP's fault and PHP has no way of detecting that.

Comment: my first stop for mail issues is the mailserver log

Comment: So it could be a problem from the server? PHPmailer returns true in both cases. But the mail is only sent when I use a mail with own domain name.

Comment: your server, any server between you and the destination, the destination server, the user. take your pick

Comment: This is the intended behavior from email servers. Look into [SPF records](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en).

Comment: are you talking about sending to gmail or sending from a gmail account?

Comment: @Dagon, `$mail->From = $_POST['inputEmail'];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
$mail->From = $_POST['inputEmail'];
$mail->FromName = $_POST['inputName'];
```

By doing that you are forging the from address, and this will cause you to fail SPF and/or DMARC checks, and either be rejected outright, or put in the spam folder.

Do this instead:

```
$mail->From = 'contacto@45norte.com';
$mail->addAddress('contacto@45norte.com'); //recipient 
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['inputEmail'], $_POST['inputName']); //recipient
```

This way you will pass SPF checks, and you will be able to reply directly to the sender.

Comment: Thanks. But at the end the problem was a server configuration.

Comment: @AlvaroLópezSánchez - Could you explain how to (re)configure the server? I'm having the same problem.